# Modelica sort variable vector after equations

Tags: modelica, dymola, openmodelica

I have a variable T, which is a vector. The variable is dependent of its derivative and therefore dependent of the time:

```
T = function(der(T))
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
T = function(der(T)); 
T = Modelica.Math.Vectors.sort(T);
```

This cannot be implemented as such, otherwise an error pops up. I used the folowing workaround:

```
T = function(der(T));
T2 = Modelica.Math.Vectors.sort(T);

when sample(0,t) then
  reinit(T, T2);
end when;
```

Is there a better way to do this, without the need for the when case or for the extra variable?

EDIT:

function(der(T)) is not a simple algebraic expression. This functions consists of multiple expressions contained in for loops and if cases.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to achieve here.  You can have `T=function(der(T))` or you can have `T=sort(function(der(T)))` but you cannot have both.  Do you understand why (i.e., single assignment rule)?

Comment: Yes, I understand the assignment rule. The problem is that the function consists of for loops and if cases. So it is impossible to write that between de sort() command.

Comment: You'll need to have two variables.  One holding the unsorted version of the vector, e.g. `T`, and a separate one, e.g. `T2`, that holds the sorted one.  You can't have one variable that holds both.

Comment: I think perhaps I see the issue here.  Is it important that your "function" get the *sorted* version of `der(T)`?  Is that why you want `T` and `T2` to be the same?  In general, this isn't going to work for the reasons you mention in your edit.  You want to take the derivative of `T` but, as you point out, it contains `for` loops and `if` statements (which cannot, in general, be differentiated).  Again, I would suggest you elaborate on why you need to do this and it may turn out that it isn't even necessary.

Comment: I'm trying if I can use the sort function, instead of modelling a difficult physical process. I'm afraid I cannot go into further detail.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it works with:

```
T = Modelica.Math.Vectors.sort(function(der(T)));
```

Comment: The problem is, that function(der(T)) is not an algebraic expression. It consists of multiple expressions contained in for loops and if cases.

Comment: Can't you put the functionality in an algorithm in a function?